# clearContents on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks to @Guy for getting me this far...

```
function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [ {name: "Clear", functionName: "clear"} ];
   ss.addMenu("Admin", menuEntries);
}

function clear() {
   var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i > sheets.length; i++) {
  var range = sheet[i].getRange("A1:A5");
     range.clearContents();
}
}
```

My question is why will is not clear the contents of the cell in google docs, do the sheet names have anything to do with it. Dose it matter how many sheets are in the document?

I have run the script on different files all with the same result. The admin menu is added to the top bar but when I click clear in the menu nothing happens.

I am very new to this, and I have tried different things but nothing is getting the data to clear.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to me missing an s

```
function clear() {
   var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i > sheets.length; i++) {
  var range = sheet[i].getRange("A1:A5");
     range.clearContents();
}
}
```

should be:

```
var range = sheets[i].getRange("A1:A5"); // sheets with an s
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you,

i have tried using the below mention script to clear contents of active sheet.

```
var gensheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
gensheet.clearContents();
```

this can be tried to clear entire sheet many ways also.

and to clear contents of a specified range try this

```
   var gensheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mobilization');
       gensheet.getRange(6, 1, 50, 49).clear({contentsOnly:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using `clearContents();` instead of `clearContent();` which is the correct form. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent()).

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [ {name: "Clear", functionName: "clear"} ];
ss.addMenu("Admin", menuEntries);
}

function clear() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i > sheets.length; i++) {
var range = sheet[i].getRange("A1:A5");
range.clearContent();
}
}
```